# необходимо считать в массив с файла

Tags: c#, .net, файлы

С#

Я не могу считать массив с файла("input.txt") в файле находятся натуральные, но их количество будет меняться 
Пытался сделать это с помощью StreamReader, не вышло:( .

Помогите пожалуйста )

Comment: добавь код который ты пробовал и распиши как именно не вышло

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readalllines

Comment: StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input.txt");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt");

        string[] line0 = sr.ReadLine().Split(); // this line don't ne
        string[] line = sr.ReadLine().Split(); //line[0] line[1] line[2]

        int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(line[0]);
        int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(line[1]);
        int x3 = Convert.ToInt32(line[2]);

        int[] ar = new int[3];
        ar[0] = x3 % 10;
        ar[1] = x2 % 10;
        ar[2] = x1 % 10;
        sw.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", ar[0],ar[1],ar[2]);
        sr.Close();
        sw.Close();

Comment: это задача c cайта      https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=149&ins=1#solution